# Add Content HyperLink to Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder if anyone could help me out.

I have over 20 sheets I have created a content hyperlink in the first sheet.
Now I want to allocate that content hyperlink to the sheet.  So when I am on sheet 20 and click a link in sheet 20 it takes me back to the contents sheet.
It works for active sheets but doesnt for the rest of the sheets. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub AddContentLinctoSheets111()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To WS_Count

Range("G1").Select
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "CONTENTS!A1", TextToDisplay:="CONTENTS!A1"
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: In the loop> For I = 1 To WS_Count .... try to refer at Worksheets(I)...  and not to ActiveSheet

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub AddLinkstoAllSheets()
       Dim ws As Worksheet
         For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          If ws.Name <> "CONTENTS" Then
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add _
              Anchor:=ws.Range("G1"), _
              Address:="", _
              SubAddress:="Contents!A1", _
              TextToDisplay:="Contains Page"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Please try to add some context to your solution, it will help others to understand why you are using this particular approach.